# Mongodb - How to remove element of document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Schemas and the produce the below data when I print the Match out to the web page, but this team[] field, I believe it is there from a previous point in development and I have since managed to get the hometeam to save to the correct place, how do I get rid of this field as it is unnecessary?

Team Schema

```
var Team = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'name' : { type : String,
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
              index : { unique : true }
            }
});
```

Match Schema

```
var Match = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique: true,
    type: Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'hometeam' : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
  'awayteam' : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
});
```

Matches output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5112aeaf064432060d000002",
    "team": [
      {
        "key": 1360178863022,
        "_id": "5112aeaf064432060d000003"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "key": 1360178863022
  },
  {
    "hometeam": "5106e7ef9afe3a430e000007",
    "_id": "5113b7ca71ec596125000005",
    "__v": 0,
    "key": 1360246730427
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has a schema on which it does validation, but MongoDB does not. Mongo is schemaless, meaning that it has absolutely no idea what your data is supposed to represent. Therefore, if your schema has allowed such changes to be made in the past, it is your responsibility to clean up the mess you made. You can do a query against a value only the old scheme would have and call remove on that to get rid of the documents, but otherwise it's mostly manual labor (or dropping everything -- which is great for development too).